# Wrong colors in JLabel when using HTML string

Tags: java, swing, awt, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm trying to use HTML styling in a JLabel and convert the BufferedImage to jpg. However the colors are quite different than what I expect.

Here is the code:

```
val html = "<html><body style='width: 400px; padding: 5px; margin:0; color:#000;'>" + "<h1>teststring1</h1>" + key + " <h2>teststring</h2><body></html>"
val textLabe = new JLabel(html)
textLabe.setSize(textLabe.getPreferredSize)
val d: Dimension = textLabe.getPreferredSize
val bi: BufferedImage = new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
val g = bi.createGraphics
textLabe.paint(g)

val a = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", a)
```

As you can see the text color is not black and the background is black instead of white. I tried to set setForeground(Colors.white), setBackground(Colors.white) and setOpaque(true) but the background color turn into pink in this case.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the background color turn into pink in this case.

Not sure what JDK/JRE you are using, but there seems to be something wrong with the `JPEGImageWriter`, particularly the way it handles alpha.

Try using a `BufferedImage` of `TYPE_INT_RGB` or `TYPE_3BYTE_RGB` instead of `TYPE_INT_ARGB` as a workaround, or alternatively write the image as a PNG.

Then, use `setOpaque(true)` to make sure the background is painted, and `setBackground(Color.WHITE)` to set the correct background color. You *should* now have a correctly colored output image.

Comment: I actually tried other options but I couldn't think that TYPE_INT_RGB  would work. It's working fine now, thanks!